# \! something command not works expected in remote mysql conecction

Tags: mysql, shell

I wanna run some commands from `mysql shell` remote, but when I run the command  for example

```
mysql -u root -h remoteip -p 

mysql> \! nano somefile.txt

mysql> \! python somescript.py
```

This command try to access to my michine, no the remote machine,

is there some way to run a native commands from `mysql shell`?

some like

```
mysql> select execute('python /tmp/script.py');
```

**Note:**

please dont tell me that use ssh because is special case when I just have access to mysql remote shell no more.

Comment: The `mysql>` client prompt is only active for the current client connection. But if it is really `mysqldump` that you need to run, that may just as well be run remotely.  If you need additional permissions not currently granted to your remote user, you will need to negotiate that with your DBA - you cannot run shell commands from MySQL (this would be a security nightmare)

Comment: If allowing a remote sql connection allowed local shell commands that would be a **HUGE** security problem and would negate just about all possible security utility of the various mysql/etc. acl/permissions/etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mysqldump -u username -p -h remote.site.com DBNAME > backup.sql
```

to acheive the same you must have to create mysql use in remote server and should provide your machine ipadress.
As well make sure you can access mysql from your local machine.

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE ON <dbname>.* TO 
'<user>'@'ipaddressofm/cfromwhich you want to acess' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
```